# S'agit-il d'une question indirecte?

Tags: grammaire

Dans la phrase suivante: 
"Je ne sais pas si on peut lui faire confiance".
Est-ce que la proposition "si on peut lui faire confiance" est une interrogation indirecte?

Answer (score 2):

Je pense que oui.

La question serait:

> Peut-on lui faire confiance ?

La plupart des exemples utilisent "*j'aimerais savoir si -*" ou "*Je me demande si -*" mais je pense que "*je ne sais pas si -*" donne aussi une interrogation indirecte, la construction est exactement la même.

Comment: Merci. L'interrogation indirecte est bien la subordonnée "si on peut lui faire confiance" et non pas toute la phrase "Je ne sais pas si on peut lui faire confiance.", n'est-ce pas?

Comment: @Othman Oui, correct.